# How to get start and end of the week between two dates

Tags: php

I have two dates

```
$start_date = '2015-09-21';
$end_Date = '2016-09-21';
```

What i want to get like this

```
Week  =  Monday           Friday 
36    =  2015-09-21       2015-09-25
37    =  2015-09-28       2015-10-02
38    =  2015-10-05       2015-10-09
.
.
38   =  2016-09-19        2016-09-24
```

The date difference may be of one year or more. What i need to get is exact each week Monday and Friday dates between this time interval.

I used this method

```
$weeks = array();
    while ($start_date < $end_Date )
    {  
        $weeks[] = date('W', $start_date ); 
        $start_date += strtotime('+1 week', 0);
    }

    function getStartAndEndDate($week, $year)
    {

        $time = strtotime("1 January $year", time());
        $day = date('w', $time);
        $time += ((7*$week)+1-$day)*24*3600;
        $return[0] = date('Y-m-d', $time);
        $time += 6*24*3600;
        $return[1] = date('Y-m-d', $time);
        return $return;
    }
```

When i call this function, I need to put week number and year to get exact dates. But I cant get year with the particular week. I can managed to get week from the start date or end date.

```
    $current_year = date("Y", strtotime($fromdate));
```

Any one suggest me to get the exact year with the week number

Comment: Need some more description. Did you start with Monday??

Comment: yes... i need to get weeks between two dates and difference may be of one year or two years. I need to get all weeks between these two dates and start and end dates of the week  also

Comment: Did you try anything???

Comment: I made two functions for this, first i get week number and then convert week numbers to dates but the problem is I cant get exact output what i want because in those functions, I need to get year of the each week and I  cant find any way to get exact year of the week.. I only managed to get start or end date year.

Comment: You should share some code which you have started with.

Comment: As you mention the Week in your expected output is not the actual week number of the year.

Comment: @AftabHafeez, Make a try and let me know. [Online Example](https://3v4l.org/1cYUM)

Comment: It works for me...  can i get week number with every date???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you need to convert the time into object, after that calculate the difference. Now calculate the weeks between the given dates. Now its time loop through the weeks from start date, I use `DateInterval('P4D')` to ahead the date by 4 days and then echo two dates then again `DateInterval('P3D')` to complete the week and this is repeated.

```
$start_date = '2015-09-21';
$end_Date = '2016-09-21';

$date1 = new DateTime($start_date);
$date2 = new DateTime($end_Date);
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);

$weeks = floor(($interval->days) / 7);

for($i = 1; $i <= $weeks; $i++){    
    $week = $date1->format("W");
    $date1->add(new DateInterval('P4D'));
    echo $week." = ".$start_date." - ".$date1->format('Y-m-d')."<br/>";
    $date1->add(new DateInterval('P3D'));
    $start_date = $date1->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

**Output:**

```
39 = 2015-09-21 - 2015-09-25
40 = 2015-09-28 - 2015-10-02
41 = 2015-10-05 - 2015-10-09
42 = 2015-10-12 - 2015-10-16
43 = 2015-10-19 - 2015-10-23
44 = 2015-10-26 - 2015-10-30
45 = 2015-11-02 - 2015-11-06
46 = 2015-11-09 - 2015-11-13
47 = 2015-11-16 - 2015-11-20
48 = 2015-11-23 - 2015-11-27
49 = 2015-11-30 - 2015-12-04
50 = 2015-12-07 - 2015-12-11
51 = 2015-12-14 - 2015-12-18
52 = 2015-12-21 - 2015-12-25
53 = 2015-12-28 - 2016-01-01
01 = 2016-01-04 - 2016-01-08
02 = 2016-01-11 - 2016-01-15
03 = 2016-01-18 - 2016-01-22
04 = 2016-01-25 - 2016-01-29
05 = 2016-02-01 - 2016-02-05
06 = 2016-02-08 - 2016-02-12
07 = 2016-02-15 - 2016-02-19
08 = 2016-02-22 - 2016-02-26
09 = 2016-02-29 - 2016-03-04
10 = 2016-03-07 - 2016-03-11
11 = 2016-03-14 - 2016-03-18
12 = 2016-03-21 - 2016-03-25
13 = 2016-03-28 - 2016-04-01
14 = 2016-04-04 - 2016-04-08
15 = 2016-04-11 - 2016-04-15
16 = 2016-04-18 - 2016-04-22
17 = 2016-04-25 - 2016-04-29
18 = 2016-05-02 - 2016-05-06
19 = 2016-05-09 - 2016-05-13
20 = 2016-05-16 - 2016-05-20
21 = 2016-05-23 - 2016-05-27
22 = 2016-05-30 - 2016-06-03
23 = 2016-06-06 - 2016-06-10
24 = 2016-06-13 - 2016-06-17
25 = 2016-06-20 - 2016-06-24
26 = 2016-06-27 - 2016-07-01
27 = 2016-07-04 - 2016-07-08
28 = 2016-07-11 - 2016-07-15
29 = 2016-07-18 - 2016-07-22
30 = 2016-07-25 - 2016-07-29
31 = 2016-08-01 - 2016-08-05
32 = 2016-08-08 - 2016-08-12
33 = 2016-08-15 - 2016-08-19
34 = 2016-08-22 - 2016-08-26
35 = 2016-08-29 - 2016-09-02
36 = 2016-09-05 - 2016-09-09
37 = 2016-09-12 - 2016-09-16
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by 'Yogesh Singasane' won't work if the start date is 1st Jan and it ends up in week 52 of the previous year. Here is the modified code that seems to be covering the same corner case:

```
$start_date = '2023-01-01';
$end_Date = '2023-01-31';

$startTime = strtotime($start_date);
$endTime = strtotime($end_Date);

$weeks = array();
$date = new DateTime();
$i=0;
while ($startTime < $endTime) {  
    $weeks[$i]['week'] = date('W', $startTime);
    if(date("m-d", strtotime($start_date)) == '01-01' && date('W', $startTime) >= 52){
        $weeks[$i]['year'] = date('Y', $startTime) - 1 ; 
    }
    else{
        $weeks[$i]['year'] = date('Y', $startTime); 
    }
    $date->setISODate($weeks[$i]['year'], $weeks[$i]['week']);
    $weeks[$i]['Monday']=$date->format('Y-m-d'); 
    $weeks[$i]['Friday'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($weeks[$i]['Monday'] . "+4 days"));
    $startTime += strtotime('+1 week', 0);
    $i++;
}
var_dump($weeks);
```

P.S. Google brought me here, and I wanted to post to help others like me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$start_date = '2015-09-21';
$end_Date = '2016-09-21';

$startTime = strtotime($start_date);
$endTime = strtotime($end_Date);

$weeks = array();
$date = new DateTime();
$i=0;
while ($startTime < $endTime) {  
    $weeks[$i]['week'] = date('W', $startTime);
    $weeks[$i]['year'] = date('Y', $startTime); 
    $date->setISODate($weeks[$i]['year'], $weeks[$i]['week']);
    $weeks[$i]['Monday']=$date->format('Y-m-d'); 
    $weeks[$i]['Friday'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($weeks[$i]['Monday'] . "+4 days"));
    $startTime += strtotime('+1 week', 0);
    $i++;
}
var_dump($weeks);
```