# get number of days from given dates in a array php

Tags: php, arrays, date

I am trying to get the number of days from the first date to the second date, and then from the second date to the third date and so on.
I have a array like this

```
$dates = array(
    2016 - 02 - 01,
    2016 - 03 - 01,
    2016 - 04 - 01,
    2016 - 05 - 01,
    2016 - 06 - 01,
    2016 - 07 - 01,
    2016 - 09 - 01,
    2016 - 11 - 01,
    2016 - 12 - 01,
    2017 - 01 - 01,
    2017 - 12 - 01
);
```

I want to get the number of days from 2016-02-01 to 2016-03-01, and then from 2016-03-01 to 2016-04-01 and so on, if you notice there are some gaps in the dates as in they do jump for more than 1 month.
And I want it in a array like this

```
array()(
    [0] => 0,
    [1] => 30,
    [2] => 60
    //so on ...
)
```

Here is how I am doing it but I am getting errors like `uninitialized string offset`  and I guess the way I am doing is wrong most probably

```
public  function rangeDates()
{
    $dates = array(
        '2016-02-01',
        '2016-03-01',
        '2016-04-01',
        '2016-05-01',
        '2016-06-01',
        '2016-07-01',
        '2016-09-01',
        '2016-11-01',
        '2016-12-01',
        '2017-01-01',
        '2017-12-01'
    );
    $datez = array();
    $index = 0;
    $indexone = 1;
    foreach($dates as $date)
    {
        $datez = round(abs(strtotime($date[$index]) - strtotime($date[$indexone])) / 86400);
        $index++;
        $indexone++;
    }

    echo $datez;
}
```

The dates are in **string** format, extra information that I forgot to mention is that the days needs to get added, for example if we take just the years

```
array(11) (
  [0] => (int) 0
  [1] => (int) 365
  [2] => (int) 730
  [3] => (int) 1095
  [4] => (int) 1460
  [5] => (int) 1825
  [6] => (int) 2190
  [7] => (int) 2555
  [8] => (int) 2920
  [9] => (int) 3285
  [10] => (int) 3650
```

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39630992/how-to-get-start-and-end-of-the-week-between-two-dates/39631610#39631610), and let me know is it okey for you or not. Just the first portion is all about you what you need. __If you don't understand then i can make an answer for you.__

Comment: https://eval.in/655456

Comment: @FrayneKonok Sorry I guess i did not mention it properly or its hard to understand but what I want is the difference, but then getting added to the next month, so basically 0 , 30 , 60, 90, so its like the previous days is getting added to the next days. Hope I made sense

Comment: @Anant Sorry I guess i did not mention it properly or its hard to understand but what I want is the difference, but then getting added to the next month, so basically 0 , 30 , 60, 90, so its like the previous days is getting added to the next days. Hope I made sense

Comment: @MasnadNihit, If i make comment in your try then there are some points to note **$datez =**, You initialize this as array and use just like a string also at the last you echo it.

Comment: Dates are hard. Seriously. For instance, not all days have 86400 seconds. Don't do you own maths and use builtin date functions instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is all about you need, Loop through the dates array then calculate the difference of the dates accordingly. Your loop will be run one short of the total array size, From the interval just call for the days and store it in an array.

```
$dates = array(
    "2016-02-01",
    "2016-03-01",
    "2016-04-01",
    "2016-05-01",
    "2016-06-01",
    "2016-07-01",
    "2016-09-01",
    "2016-11-01",
    "2016-12-01",
    "2017-01-01",
    "2017-12-01"
);

$datez = array();
$date = array();
$datez[] = 0;

for($i = 1; $i < count($dates) - 1; $i++){
    $start_date = $dates[$i-1];
    $end_Date = $dates[$i];

    $date1 = new DateTime($start_date);
    $date2 = new DateTime($end_Date);
    $interval = $date1->diff($date2);

    $date[]  = $interval->days;
    $datez[] = array_sum($date);
}

print_r($date);
print_r($datez);
```

[Online Example](https://3v4l.org/tQTic)

Comment: Sorry I guess i did not mention it properly or its hard to understand but what I want is the difference, but then getting added to the next month, so basically 0 , 30 , 60, 90, so its like the previous days is getting added to the next days. Hope I made sense

Comment: If it is then you should not need all these.. Just a simple start date and end date difference will done your job.

Comment: I edited the question at the top, now it tells more detailed information at the end, could you please take a look

Comment: Your question still says what i did for you.

Comment: Konock, You are getting the difference between two dates, could you please help me out by adding the previous dates?

Comment: Which one is previous date??

Comment: your function returns `[0] => (int) 0
  [1] => (int) 29
  [2] => (int) 31
  [3] => (int) 30
  [4] => (int) 31
  [5] => (int) 30
  [6] => (int) 62
  [7] => (int) 61
  [8] => (int) 30
  [9] => (int) 31
  [10] => (int) 334`

I need it to be 
`[0] => (int) 0
  [1] => (int) 29
  [2] => (int) 31+29
  [3] => (int) 30+ 31 + 29
  [4] => (int) 31 + 30 +  31 + 29
  [5] => (int) 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 29 `
 so on....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124969/discussion-between-frayne-konok-and-masnad-nihit).

Comment: Konock, could you change your answer so the right answer is there, and thanks for the help!