# Compare formatted dates in php

Tags: php

My question is:
 I have two dates in string format:

```
string(10) "2016-21-10"
string(10) "2016-05-10"
```

I can not figure out how to compare them. So basically i need the difference between the two given date. How can I achieve it?

Comment: convert the dates into the timestamp and then compare easily. If you need difference then Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39869526/get-number-of-days-from-given-dates-in-a-array-php/39869674#39869674) for the difference only.

Comment: Please do a search before asking a question. Google has SO very well indexed, you are likely to solve most of your issues with just a search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) function to create DateTime object from string.

Create two DateTime object like this,

```
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-d-m', '2016-21-10');
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-d-m', '2016-05-10');
```

To get the difference between two dates you can use [diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) function. Use it like this,

```
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
```

You can use the `$interval` variable to get the difference between two dates.