# How to get week wise dates between two dates using PHP?

Tags: php, date

I have two dates of the form:

```
Start Date: 2016-09-01 
End Date: 2016-09-30
```

Now I need to get dates week wise between these two in the following form:

```
2016-09-01 2016-09-03 (partial week)
2016-09-04 2016-09-10 (full week)
2016-09-11 2016-09-17 (full week)
2016-09-18 2016-09-24 (full week)
2016-09-25 2016-09-30 (partial week)
```

**How can I do this in PHP?**

Comment: where is your `query`?? i m searching .......

Comment: DID you search in stack for this answer??

Comment: Look at this for your solution. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39630992/how-to-get-start-and-end-of-the-week-between-two-dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39630992/how-to-get-start-and-end-of-the-week-between-two-dates)

Comment: I Just want to show partial & full week...